# Handling memory usage for big calculation in python

Tags: python, stack-overflow, sieve-of-eratosthenes, prime-factoring

I am trying to do some calculations with python, where I ran out of memory. Therefore, I want to read/write a file in order to free memory. I need a something like a very big list object, so I thought writing a line for each object in the file and read/write to that lines instead of to memory. Line ordering is important for me since I will use line numbers as index. So I was wondering how I can replace lines in python, without moving around other lines (Actually, it is fine to move lines, as long as they return back to where I expect them to be).

### Edit

I am trying to help a friend, which is worse than or equal to me in python. This code supposed to find biggest prime number, that divides given non-prime number. This code works for numbers until the numbers like 1 million, but after dead, my memory gets exhausted while trying to make numbers list.

```
# a comes from a user input
primes_upper_limit = (a+1) / 2
counter = 3L
numbers = list()
while counter <= primes_upper_limit:
    numbers.append(counter)
    counter += 2L

counter=3
i=0
half = (primes_upper_limit + 1) / 2 - 1
root = primes_upper_limit ** 0.5
while counter < root:
    if numbers[i]:
        j = int((counter*counter - 3) / 2)
        numbers[j] = 0
        while j < half:
            numbers[j] = 0
            j += counter
    i += 1
    counter = 2*i + 3
primes = [2] + [num for num in numbers if num]
for numb in reversed(primes):
    if a % numb == 0:
        print numb
        break
```

Another Edit

What about wrinting different files for each index? for example a billion of files with long integer filenames, and just a number inside of the file?

Comment: Let's solve the cause of running out-of-memory: tell us about the calculation, or post the code? You might also try NumPy.

Comment: You might get better answers if you explain what actual problem you're tying to solve.

Comment: I added some more explanation and my code in my original question.

Comment: I would advise not bringing the filesystem into this. Do you really want a billion files? It'll be so slow. If you really want to augment your memory with the disk, you can make a swap file.

Comment: Do you need to store a list of all prime factors then pick the largest (as you do)? or just find the largest prime factors directly?

Comment: I want to find largest prime divider. I am making the list so that I can sieve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the largest prime divisor of a. ([Project Euler Question 3](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems))
Your current choice of algorithm and implementation do this by:

1. Generate a list `numbers` of all candidate primes in range (3 <= n <= sqrt(a), or (a+1)/2 as you currently do)
2. Sieve the `numbers` list to get a list of primes {p} <= sqrt(a)
3. Trial Division: test the divisibility of a by each p. Store all prime divisors {q} of a.
4. Print all divisors {q}; we only want the largest.

My comments on this algorithm are below. Sieving and trial division are seriously not scalable algorithms, as Owen and I comment. For large a (billion, or trillion) you really should use NumPy. Anyway some comments on implementing this algorithm:

1. Did you know you **only need to test up to √a**, `int(math.sqrt(a))`, not (a+1)/2 as you do?
2. There is **no need to build a huge list of candidates `numbers`**, then sieve it for primeness - the numbers list is not scalable. Just **construct the list `primes` directly**. You can use while/for-loops and `xrange(3,sqrt(a)+2,2)` (which gives you an iterator). As you mention xrange() overflows at `2**31L`, but combined with the sqrt observation, you can still successfully factor up to `2**62`
3. In general this is inferior to getting the prime decomposition of a, i.e. every time you find a prime divisor p | a, you only need to continue to **sieve the remaining factor a/p or a/p² or a/p³ or whatever)**. Except for the rare case of very large primes (or pseudoprimes), this will greatly reduce the magnitude of the numbers you are working with.
4. Also, **you only ever need to generate the list of primes {p} once**; thereafter store it and do lookups, not regenerate it.
   So I would separate out `generate_primes(a)` from `find_largest_prime_divisor(a)`. Decomposition helps greatly.

Here is my rewrite of your code, but performance still falls off in the billions (a > 10**11 +1) due to keeping the sieved list. We can use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects) instead of list for primes, to get a faster O(1) append() operation, but that's a minor optimization.

```
# Prime Factorization by trial division

from math import ceil,sqrt
from collections import deque

# Global list of primes (strictly we should use a class variable not a global)
#primes = deque()
primes = []

def is_prime(n):
    """Test whether n is divisible by any prime known so far"""
    global primes
    for p in primes:
         if n%p == 0:
             return False #  n was divisible by p
    return True # either n is prime, or divisible by some p larger than our list    
def generate_primes(a):
    """Generate sieved list of primes (up to sqrt(a)) as we go"""
    global primes
    primes_upper_limit = int(sqrt(a))
    # We get huge speedup by using xrange() instead of range(), so we have to seed the list with 2
    primes.append(2)
    print "Generating sieved list of primes up to", primes_upper_limit, "...",
    # Consider prime candidates 2,3,5,7... in increasing increments of 2
    #for number in [2] + range(3,primes_upper_limit+2,2):
    for number in xrange(3,primes_upper_limit+2,2):
        if is_prime(number): # use global 'primes'
            #print "Found new prime", number
            primes.append(number) # Found a new prime larger than our list
    print "done"    
def find_largest_prime_factor(x, debug=False):
    """Find all prime factors of x, and return the largest."""
    global primes
    # First we need the list of all primes <= sqrt(x)    
    generate_primes(x)
    to_factor = x # running value of the remaining quantity we need to factor
    largest_prime_factor = None
    for p in primes:
        if debug: print "Testing divisibility by", p
        if to_factor%p != 0:
            continue
        if debug: print "...yes it is"
        largest_prime_factor = p
        # Divide out all factors of p in x (may have multiplicity)
        while to_factor%p == 0:
            to_factor /= p
        # Stop when all factors have been found
        if to_factor==1:
            break
    else:
        print "Tested all primes up to sqrt(a), remaining factor must be a single prime > sqrt(a) :", to_factor
    print "\nLargest prime factor of x is", largest_prime_factor
    return largest_prime_factor
```

Comment: I think the purpose of `numbers` is that it stores primes -- it's like the sieve of eratosthenes.

Comment: @Owen: sure, but it's unnecessary to store all of it, certainly as a list rather than a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set). Should we give him a literal implementation of a really bad (and unscalable) algorithm, or help him understand what would make it a better algorithm?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that problem started with range/xrange doesn't accepting long objects. And since I am calculating primes with sieve, not making a list doesn't work. And not using sieve is really slow for this kind of calculation.

Comment: @yasar: but as I pointed out you only need to test prime factors up to sqrt(a), not (a+1)/2. You only need longs if a >= 2**31

Comment: @yasar11732 I guess it would depend on how big `a` can get -- are you only going up into the billions? Because then you should be OK. If you're going into the trillions, it will be worse, but even then you'd have a trillion-long sieve.

Comment: Your assumption about sqrt(x) is wrong. sqrt(15) = 3.8, biggest prime divider of 15 is 5. 5 is clearly bigger than 3.8 . I tried your code, and it failed for numbers like 12,15.

Comment: No, you do in fact only need to test prime factors up to int(sqrt(a)) (i.e. 3 in this case). If there is any remaining factor left (in this case 15/3 = 5), we know it must be a single prime between sqrt(a) and a. This saves you a huge amount of sieving. I verified my code does work on 12 and 15 (why do you claim it doesn't?).

Comment: I copy paster your code, supplied find_largest_prime_factor function with 15, it returned None. supplied it with 12, It returned 2

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out: `xrange(min,max,step)` will not return the value max, hence we add 2 to max. Also, I added the `for..else` just to explicitly print a note when we hit the case you mention.

Comment: I managed to replace `range()` with `xrange()`, gives a huge speedup since we are not (accidentally) creating a huge unwanted list.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is not an easy task. They way I interpreted it, you want to keep a file handle open, and use the file as a place to store character data.

Say you had a file like,

```
a
b
c
```

and you wanted to replace 'b' with 'bb'. That's going to be a pain, because the file actually looks like `a\nb\nc` -- you can't just overwrite the `b`, you need another byte.

My advice would be to try and find a way to make your algorithm work without using a file for extra storage. If you got a stack overflow, chances are you didn't really run out of memory, you overran the call stack, which is *much* smaller.

You could try reworking your algorithm to not be recursive. Sometimes you can use a `list` to substitute for the call stack -- but there are many things you could do and I don't think I could give much general advice not seeing your algorithm.

**edit**

Ah I see what you mean... when the list

```
while counter <= primes_upper_limit:
    numbers.append(counter)
    counter += 2L
```

grows really big, you could run out of memory. So I guess you're basically doing a sieve, and that's why you have the big list `numbers`? It makes sense. If you want to keep doing it this way, you could try a `numpy` `bool` array, because it will use substantially less memory per cell:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.repeat(True, a/2)
```

Or (and maybe this is not appealing) you could go with an entirely different approach that doesn't use a big list, such as factoring the number entirely and picking the biggest factor.

Something like:

```
factors = [ ]
tail = a

while tail > 1:
    j = 2
    while 1:
        if tail % j == 0:
            factors.append(j)
            tail = tail / j
            print('%s %s' % (factors, tail))
            break
        else:
            j += 1
```

ie say you were factoring `20`: `tail` starts out as `20`, then you find `2` `tail` becomes `10`, then it becomes `5`.

This is not terrible efficient and will become *way* too slow for a large (billions) prime number, but it's ok for numbers with small factors.

I mean your sieve is good too, until you start running out of memory ;). You could give `numpy` a shot.

Comment: I added algorithm to my original question.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, I didn't quite get what you meant by factoring number entirely and picking the biggest factor.

Comment: Ah sorry. I meant, start with `a`, factor it into `b * c`, factor `c` into `d * e`, and so on.

Comment: Can you link to a sample algorithm for factoring the number entirely. I am not a guru on algorithms, and couldn't figure out how would I do that.

Comment: That's called finding the [Integer Factorization or Prime Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) of a. In this case you're using the Trial Division method (that's the simplest method).

Answer (score 0):

[pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) is excellent for working with and storing huge amounts of data. But first start with implementing the comments in smci's answer to minimize the amount of numbers you need to store.

Answer (score 0):

For a number with only twelve digits, as in Project Euler #3, no fancy integer factorization method is needed, and there is no need to store intermediate results on disk. Use this algorithm to find the factors of n:

1. Set f = 2.
2. If n = 1, stop.
3. If f * f > n, print n and stop.
4. Divide n by f, keeping both the quotient q and the remainder r.
5. If r = 0, print q, divide n by q, and go to Step 2.
6. Otherwise, increase f by 1 and go to Step 3.

This just does trial division by every integer until it reaches the square root, which indicates that the remaining cofactor is prime. Each factor is printed as it is found.